# Is it possible to have Bootstrap work off of a <div>'s width instead of the viewport width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

On our site, we are using the Bootstrap v3 grid system to control the layout of the page. When a user resizes their browser window, the bootstrap system kicks into gear and all works well.

We have a new use case, where a user needs to design a page for a given browser width, but we want them to do it without having to resize their own browser.

We have an outer  that wraps the content and is set to a fixed with, and we want Bootstrap to check the width of that content and apply the responsive layout based on that 's width, no the browser window width.

Is this possible? And if so, can someone point me to an example or documentation of how to achieve this?

Comment: have you considered importing it with a frame, I know, but it should give the correct dimensions to view port

Comment: haven't tried this yet, might work, will think about it and try

Comment: You could also look into how browsers inspection tools do this. They are quickly able to switch between viewport/device types without much fuss.

Comment: yeah that's a good point, i'm searching but only finding stuff about how to use the browser tools rather than how they are able to alter the window size

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar case and used [ResizeObserver](https://github.com/juggle/resize-observer) to observe the width of an element to base CSS from rather than the viewport.  Learn more:

https://philipwalton.com/articles/responsive-components-a-solution-to-the-container-queries-problem/

https://www.w3.org/TR/resize-observer/

Note: this is currently only supported in Chrome

Follow up: CSS container queries have been released as of April 2021, but there is no browser support for them yet – https://caniuse.com/css-container-queries